# HOW DO I PARSE THE DATA IN THESE HTML TAGS?

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.5

I am a python newbie.I was trying to get some data from my school site. Below is the code I wrote to scrap only the news items. It works but I want the title, date and paragraph to be in new lines. I feel there is something missing in my code but I don't have a hang on it. Need your help guys.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen


page = urlopen("http://www.kibabiiuniversity.ac.ke")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

for i in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "blog-thumbnail-inside"}):
    print (i.get_text())
    print ("----------" *20)
```

And here is the html tag structure of the page I'm trying to scrape.

```
<div class="blog-thumbnail-inside">
    <h2 class="blog-thumbnail-title post-widget-title-color gdl-title">
        <a href="http://www.kibabiiuniversity.ac.ke">
            Completion of fees & collection of exam cards.
        </a>
    </h2>
    <div class="blog-thumbnail-info post-widget-info-color gdl-divider">
        <div class="blog-thumbnail-date">Posted on 09 Jan 2017</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-thumbnail-context">
        <div class="blog-thumbnail-content">
            Download the information on fee payment and collection of exam cards..
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "blog-thumbnail-inside"}):
    print (i.get_text('\n'))  #You can specify a string to be used to join the bits of text together
    print ("----------" *20)
```

out:

```
Final Undergraduate Examination Timetable for Semester 1 2016/2017
Posted on 11 Jan 2017
Download Undergraduate Timetable
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Vacancies for Administrative and Teaching Positions
Posted on 11 Jan 2017
Kibabii University is a fully fledged public institution of higher education and research in Kenya with a student population of 6400 and staff population of 346. The University seeks to appoint innovative individuals with experience and excellent credentials
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the bit I was missing.